# IntelliJ IDEA - can't find module-info.java file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, java-9

I am following a course where I need to create a module-info.java file but I can't find it on new.

I started om jdk11 but also downloaded jdk9 but still can't find it.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone know how to add it so I can create it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option [is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VevR.png) on the [source roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html) (marked in blue) if you are using JDK 9+ and have configured the 9+ language level [for the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuPPw.png) and [for the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHnpQ.png).